# Taking Multiple Inputs from the User and Including Spaces

Tags: c, validation, scanf, newline, user-input

I have a problem taking multiple inputs from the user with scanf. I am using [^\n] to account for spaces in the input but when I press enter for the first input I believe it just assumes that I am entering a newline character for my other two user inputs. As you can see in my code I ask for 3 user inputs: gradeWanted, currentGrade, and finalWeight. However when I input something such as A for gradWanted and then press enter the other two scanf's just run and don't allow me to input anything. I need to account for spaces in my currentGrade and finalWeight inputs to make sure something like "80 waffles" isn't entered by the user.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

// this function will take in the addresses of grade, weight, percent, and letterGrade as the argument
void getValidInfo(double *grade, double *weight, double *percent, char *letterGrade) {
  double percentWanted = 0.0;
  char currentGrade[100], finalWeight[100];
  char gradeWanted[1];

  // get user input of desired letter grade and convert to percentage
  printf("Enter the grade you want in the class: ");
  scanf("%s", gradeWanted);

  if (strlen(gradeWanted) != 1) {
    printf("Invalid formatting. Ending program.\n");
    exit(0);
  }
  if (gradeWanted[0] == 'A' || gradeWanted[0] == 'a') {
      percentWanted = 90.0;
  } else if (gradeWanted[0] == 'B' || gradeWanted[0] == 'b') {
      percentWanted = 80.0;
  } else if (gradeWanted[0] == 'C' || gradeWanted[0] == 'c') {
      percentWanted = 70.0;
  } else if (gradeWanted[0] == 'D' || gradeWanted[0] == 'd') {
      percentWanted = 60.0;
  } else if (gradeWanted[0] == 'F' || gradeWanted[0] == 'f') {
      percentWanted = 0.0;
  } else {
      printf("Unknown Grade Received: %s. Ending program.\n", gradeWanted);
      exit(0);
}
  // get the users grade in the class and check for valid input
  printf("Enter your current percent in the class: ");
  scanf("%[^\n]s", currentGrade);

  if(atof(currentGrade) < 0) {  // converts the input of currentGrade to a double and checks if it is negative
    printf("The number you last entered should have been positive. Ending program.\n");
    exit(0);
  }
  // iterates through currentGrade to check if it is a number
  for (int i = 0; i < strlen(currentGrade); ++i) {
    if (!(isdigit(currentGrade[i])) && (currentGrade[i] != '.') != 0) {
      printf("Invalid formatting. Ending program.\n");
      exit(0);
  }
}
  // get the weight of the final from the user and check for valid input
  printf("Enter the weight of the final: ");
  scanf("%[^\n]s", finalWeight);

  if (atof(finalWeight) < 0) {  // converts the input of finalWeight to a double and checks if it is negative
    printf("The number you last entered should have been positive. Ending program.\n");
    exit(0);
}
  // iterates through finalWeight to check if it is a number
  for (int i = 0; i < strlen(finalWeight); ++i) {
    if (!(isdigit(finalWeight[i])) && (finalWeight[i] != '.') != 0) {
      printf("Invalid formatting. Ending program.\n");
      exit(0);
}
}
  *grade = atof(currentGrade);  // sets the value of the string currentGrade as a double to the address of grade
  *weight = atof(finalWeight);  // sets the value of the string finalWeight as a double to the address of weight
  *percent = percentWanted;     // sets the value of percentWanted to the address of percent
  *letterGrade = gradeWanted[0];   // sets the value of gradeWanted to the address of letterGrade
}

void calcGradeNeededOnFinal(double grade, double weight, double percent, char letterGrade[1]) {
  // calculate the grade needed on the final test to get the desired grade of the user
  double gradeNeededOnFinal = (percent - (grade * (1.0 - weight/100.0))) / (weight/100.0);
  if (gradeNeededOnFinal < 0) {
    printf("You cannot score low enough on the final to get a %s in the class.\n", letterGrade);
  }
  else if (gradeNeededOnFinal > 100.0) {
    printf("You cannot get a %s in the class because you would need to score at least %.2lf%% on the final.\n", letterGrade, gradeNeededOnFinal);
  }
  else {
  printf("You need a grade of at least %.2lf%% on the final to get a %s in the class.\n", gradeNeededOnFinal, letterGrade);
}
}

int main() {
  double grade;
  double weight;
  double percent;
  char letterGrade[1];

  getValidInfo(&grade, &weight, &percent, letterGrade);   // sends the addresses of these variables to getValidInfo
  calcGradeNeededOnFinal(grade, weight, percent, letterGrade);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes, yes it does. `"%c"`, `"%[..]"`, and `"%n"` do NOT ignore leading whitespace. Instead, use `if (scanf(" %[^\n]", currentGrade)) != 1) { /* handle error */ }` -- note the the `' '` (space) before `" %[..]"` and note the  `'s'` is removed -- it has no place in using the `"%[..]"` conversion specifier. Better, take all user-input with `fgets()` and use `sscanf()` to parse values from the buffer filled.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Thank you!! This worked.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on the comment, a full 90%+ of all input questions on this site involve the misuse of `scanf()`. It is so full of pitfalls for the new C programmer, it is recommended (and good programming practice) to take all user-input with `fgets()` and then parse any needed values from the array (buffer) filled using `sscanf()`.

That way, what remains in the input buffer (`stdin`) does not depend on the *conversion specifier* used, or whether a *matching* or *input* failure occurs. In this case, you do not even need to worry about trimming the `'\n'` from the end of the string filled by `fgets()`. (which if you filled `array` with `fgets()`, you would simply use `array[strcspn(array, "\n")] = 0;` to accomplish, if required)

Never use `atoi()`, `atof()`, etc.. They provide ZERO error checking and will happily accept `atoi ("my cow");` and silently return `0` without any indication of the failure. At minimum, use `sscanf()` or for full error detection use `strtol()` or `strtod()`, etc.

In your case here, using `fgets()` and a single array (buffer) called `buf` makes things so much easier. For example, let's take your `getValidInfo()` function, e.g.

```
#define MAXC 100        /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */

/* this function will take in the addresses of grade, weight, percent, and 
 * letterGrade as the argument
 */
void getValidInfo (double *grade, double *weight, double *percent,
                char *letterGrade)
{
    char buf[MAXC * 2];     /* buffer for ALL user-input */
```

(**note:** we have doubled the size of your longest expected input to set the size of the array.)

```
    // get user input of desired letter grade and convert to percentage
    printf ("Enter the grade you want in the class: ");
    if (!fgets (buf, sizeof buf, stdin)) {
        puts ("(user canceled input)");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    *letterGrade = tolower(buf[0]);         /* or simply use tolower(*buf) */
    
    if (!isalpha(*letterGrade) || *letterGrade > 'f') {
        fputs ("error: invalid gradeWanted.\n", stderr);
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
```

Now, `letterGrade` is set and no matter what the user entered, e.g. `"A cow"`, the `'A'` was correctly extracted from `buf` and nothing remains in your input stream. Note the type for `letterGrade` has been changed to a simple `char`, `char letterGrade[1];` is NOT long enough to hold a single character string -- you forgot room for the `'\0'` nul-terminating characcter (which is also plain-old ASCII `0`). As is, `letterGrade` can only be the *empty-string* or hold a single character but CANNOT be treated as a string.

Also, converting `letterGrade` `tolower()` simplifies the logic needed. Save a copy of the original before converting `tolower()` if you want to save the case -- that is left to you.

Instead of using a *Daisy-Chain* of `if ... else if ... else if ... else` you can us a simple `switch(*letterGrade) { .. }` statement to simplify assigning `*percent`, e.g.

```
    switch (*letterGrade) {
        case 'a':   *percent = 90.; break;
        case 'b':   *percent = 80.; break;
        case 'c':   *percent = 70.; break;
        case 'd':   *percent = 60.; break;
        case 'f':   *percent =  0.; break;
        default :   fputs ("error: we shouldn't be here...\n", stderr);
                    exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
```

For `grade` and `weight` the input routine needed is almost identical (except for the names), so they will look identical, e.g.

```
    // get the users grade in the class and check for valid input
    printf ("Enter your current grade in the class: ");
    if (!fgets (buf, sizeof buf, stdin)) {
        puts ("(user canceled input)");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if (sscanf (buf, "%lf", grade) != 1) {
        fputs ("error: invalid double input for grade.\n", stderr);
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if (*grade < 0) {
        fputs ("error: grade entered was negative.\n", stderr);
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // get the weight of the final from the user and check for valid input
    printf ("Enter the weight of the final: ");
    if (!fgets (buf, sizeof buf, stdin)) {
        puts ("(user canceled input)");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if (sscanf (buf, "%lf", weight) != 1) {
        fputs ("error: invalid double input for weight.\n", stderr);
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if (*weight < 0) {
        fputs ("error: weight entered was negative.\n", stderr);
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}
```

That's it, function done, though you may want to handle errors without exiting the program, but identifying and handling any error is the critical part. How you handle the error is up to you. Exiting is fine, but as you go forward, you will want to choose a function return type that can indicate success / failure so the value returned will indicate to the calling function whether the called function succeeded or failed so the error can be handled back in the caller without exiting.

Your `calcGradeNeededOnFinal()` need similar type changes but had less problems than `getValidInfo()`, e.g.

```
void calcGradeNeededOnFinal (double grade, double weight, double percent,
                            char letterGrade)
{
    // calculate the grade needed on the final for desired grade of the user
    double gradeNeededOnFinal = (percent - (grade * (1.0 - weight / 100.0))) / 
                                (weight / 100.0);
    if (gradeNeededOnFinal < 0) {
        printf ("You cannot score low enough on the final to get a %c in the class.\n",
                letterGrade);
    }
    else if (gradeNeededOnFinal > 100.0) {
        printf ("You cannot get a %c in the class, "
                "needed to score %.2lf%% on the final.\n",
                letterGrade, gradeNeededOnFinal);
    }
    else {
        printf ("You need a grade of at least %.2lf%% on the final "
                "to get a %c in the class.\n", gradeNeededOnFinal, letterGrade);
    }
}
```

Similar changes were needed in `main()` and not the changes to the parameters for the functions:

```
int main (void) {

    double grade;
    double weight;
    double percent;
    char letterGrade;

    getValidInfo (&grade, &weight, &percent, &letterGrade);
    calcGradeNeededOnFinal (grade, weight, percent, letterGrade);
    
    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/scanf_problems
Enter the grade you want in the class: a
Enter your current grade in the class: 82
Enter the weight of the final: 40
You cannot get a a in the class, needed to score 102.00% on the final.
```

Or successfully:

```
$ ./bin/scanf_problems
Enter the grade you want in the class: a
Enter your current grade in the class: 84
Enter the weight of the final: 40
You need a grade of at least 99.00% on the final to get a a in the class.
```

I'm sure there are other fixes I made that I have lost track of. Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

**Complete Code**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define MAXC 100        /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */

/* this function will take in the addresses of grade, weight, percent, and 
 * letterGrade as the argument
 */
void getValidInfo (double *grade, double *weight, double *percent,
                   char *letterGrade)
{
    char buf[MAXC * 2];     /* buffer for ALL user-input */

    // get user input of desired letter grade and convert to percentage
    printf ("Enter the grade you want in the class: ");
    if (!fgets (buf, sizeof buf, stdin)) {
        puts ("(user canceled input)");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    *letterGrade = tolower(buf[0]);         /* or simply use tolower(*buf) */
    
    if (!isalpha(*letterGrade) || *letterGrade > 'f') {
        fputs ("error: invalid gradeWanted.\n", stderr);
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    
    switch (*letterGrade) {
        case 'a':   *percent = 90.; break;
        case 'b':   *percent = 80.; break;
        case 'c':   *percent = 70.; break;
        case 'd':   *percent = 60.; break;
        case 'f':   *percent =  0.; break;
        default :   fputs ("error: we shouldn't be here...\n", stderr);
                    exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    
    // get the users grade in the class and check for valid input
    printf ("Enter your current grade in the class: ");
    if (!fgets (buf, sizeof buf, stdin)) {
        puts ("(user canceled input)");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if (sscanf (buf, "%lf", grade) != 1) {
        fputs ("error: invalid double input for grade.\n", stderr);
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if (*grade < 0) {
        fputs ("error: grade entered was negative.\n", stderr);
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // get the weight of the final from the user and check for valid input
    printf ("Enter the weight of the final: ");
    if (!fgets (buf, sizeof buf, stdin)) {
        puts ("(user canceled input)");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if (sscanf (buf, "%lf", weight) != 1) {
        fputs ("error: invalid double input for weight.\n", stderr);
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if (*weight < 0) {
        fputs ("error: weight entered was negative.\n", stderr);
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}

void calcGradeNeededOnFinal (double grade, double weight, double percent,
                             char letterGrade)
{
    // calculate the grade needed on the final for desired grade of the user
    double gradeNeededOnFinal = (percent - (grade * (1.0 - weight / 100.0))) / 
                                (weight / 100.0);
    if (gradeNeededOnFinal < 0) {
        printf ("You cannot score low enough on the final to get a %c in the class.\n",
                letterGrade);
    }
    else if (gradeNeededOnFinal > 100.0) {
        printf ("You cannot get a %c in the class, "
                "needed to score %.2lf%% on the final.\n",
                letterGrade, gradeNeededOnFinal);
    }
    else {
        printf ("You need a grade of at least %.2lf%% on the final "
                "to get a %c in the class.\n", gradeNeededOnFinal, letterGrade);
    }
}

int main (void) {

    double grade;
    double weight;
    double percent;
    char letterGrade;

    getValidInfo (&grade, &weight, &percent, &letterGrade);
    calcGradeNeededOnFinal (grade, weight, percent, letterGrade);
    
    return 0;
}
```